# movement code c++

Tags: c++, directx, artificial-intelligence

I am making a game in C++ using DirectX. I have a basic AI drawn. I want the AI to move around in a square, for example:

- the AI moves up the Z axis until it reaches 25,
- then the AI moves  along the X axis by 25,
- then down the Z axis by 25,
- then back along the X axis until it has completed a full movement in the shape of a square.

Here is what I have so far; this makes the AI move 25 up the Z axis, then 25 down the Z axis over and over again.

```
if (ghost_moves_forward == true)
{
    ghost_Z -= ghost_movement;
}
else if (ghost_moves_forward == false)
{
    ghost_Z += ghost_movement;
}


if (ghost_Z >= 25)
{
    ghost_moves_forward = true;
}
if (ghost_Z <= -25)
{
    ghost_moves_forward = false;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

---

EDIT:

```
float ghost_X = 0; //make the AI move along the x axis
float ghost_Z = 0; // makes the AI move along the Z axis
int ghost_movement = 1; // speed the AI moves
bool ghost_moves_forward = true; // true when AI moves forward, false when its moving sideways
bool ghost_moves_sideways = true;// true when moving sideways, false when moving forwards
```

I am using `ghost_X` and `ghost_Z` for the translation positions of the AI.

```
D3DXMatrixTranslation( &g_matLocal, ghost_X, 0, ghost_Z );
```

Comment: im struggling to get my head around the rest of the if loop to make the AI move in a square instead of just forwards and backwards

Comment: you're going to need to provide more code than that.. What do all the variables represent? How is this code fragment running (in a loop? recursive calls?)

Comment: You should not compare your boolean to `true` and `false`, they can be used directly in conditional statements: `if (ghost_moves_forward)`. You also do a useless test in your else: if `ghost_moves_forward` is true, it can't be false, so you can drop the `if` in the else clause.

Comment: @Luc Touraille Maybe side-effects are particularly volatile in DK10's code. Then the test might actually do something non-trivial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's assume the ghost starts at position startx, startz

```
static int square_state = 0;

// bottom left to top left is done
if(z <= startz-25 && square_state == 0)
    square_state = 1;

// top left to top right is done
if(x >= startx+25 && square_state == 1)
    square_state = 2;

// top right to bottom right is done
if(z >= startz && square_state == 2)
    square_state = 3;

// bottom right to bottom left is done
if(x <= startx && square_state == 3)
    square_state = 0;

switch(square_state)
{
case 0: // bottom left to top left
    z -= movement;  
    break;

case 1: // top left to top right
    x += movement;
    break;

case 2: // top right to bottom right
    z += movement;
    break;

case 3: // bottom right to bottom left
    x -= movement;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When going in squares instead of just up and down, you have four different movement states instead of just two, therefore a `bool` isn't any more sufficient to store the current movement state. As soon as the end condition of a movement state is reached, you go to the next movement state (the operators `++` and `%` may come handy in implementing that).

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider a 3D space and the coordinate geometry to understand and program a 3d movement.

so at the moment its merely going back and forth reason being the moving is represented on an x axis.

On a 2D space it will be

```
X component of ghost movement + y component of ghost movement.
```

on 3D you need to take all three to represent it in a 3D coordinate system

like

```
x+y+z (done through matrices)
```

read this section here for an example

[c++ first person camera in directx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049705/c-first-person-camera-in-directx)

and more on here http://www.directxtutorial.com/tutorial9/b-direct3dbasics/dx9b5.aspx

or here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452775(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of state that denotes in which moving phase the ghost is currently in (which has more states than just true and false). Moving logic then is one switch that separately handles every state.

```
switch (ghost_state)
{
case moving_up:
  ghost_Z += ghost_movement;
  if (ghost_Z >= 25)
  {
    ghost_Z = 25;
    ghost_state = moving_right;
  }
  break;

case moving_right:
  ghost_X += ghost_movement;
  if (ghost_X >= 25)
  {
    ghost_X = 25;
    ghost_state = moving_down;
  }
  break;

case moving_down:
  ghost_Z -= ghost_movement;
  if (ghost_Z <= 0)
  {
    ghost_Z = 0;
    ghost_state = moving_left;
  }
  break;

case moving_left:
  ghost_X -= ghost_movement;
  if (ghost_X <= 0)
  {
    ghost_X = 0;
    ghost_state = moving_up;
  }
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok let's assume you want to move around a 2d square space in a square pattern using X and Y values programmatically, Loop<1> would count up the X value until end (or destination)
`---------` then Loop<2> would count up until max (or destination) whilst maintaining the X value at max destination. At this point you have moved in an "L" shape

`

```
        |<y>
        |
  <x>___|
```

`

You would then reverse Loop (i.e. countdown) starting with the X values whilst maintaining the dest/max  value.

Answer (score 1):

If I were programming something like this, I would tend to make a more generic OOP solution. This would lend itself well to a project where you would like future entities to be able to move in other shapes, e.g. triangle, diamond, pentagon, etc. Depending on the scope of your program, the following is either "easily extensible" or "complete overkill".

Implement or procure a `Point` class so you can use (for example) ghost_pos.x and ghost_pos.z, rather than ghost_X and ghost_Z. This isn't strictly necessary but it makes it much easier to pass position data between functions.

Make a function `Point point_between(Point a, Point b, float distance_from_a)`, which returns some point c that lies between a and b and is `distance_from_a` units away from point a. This will require some high-school level Trig knowledge.

Make a class `LinearPath`, which represents the straight movement from one point to another over time. It should have, at a minimum, the following qualities:

- a public constructor which takes two points `begin, end`.
- a private `Point currentPosition`, which keeps track of where on the path you currently are.
- a public method `point getCurrentPosition()` - we want the user to be able to read currentPosition, but not overwrite it.
- a public method `move(float distance)`, which moves `currentPosition` towards `end` (hint: use `point_between` for this).
- a public method `done` which returns true if `currentPosition` equals `end`.

Make a class `LoopedPath`, which represents movement from point A to B to C ... to Z and back to A again. It should have:

- A constructor which takes a collection of Points (array, Vector, Queue, whatever)
- A private `LinearPath currentPath`, which keeps track of which linear path you are currently on.
- A public method `move(float distance)` which first checks to see if the currentPath is `done`, and if so re-instantiates it with the next untraversed point. Then it calls `currentPath.move(distance)`.
- A public method `point getCurrentPosition()`.

Give your Ghost class an instance of LoopedPath. Instantiate it with the four points of the square (in your example, (0,0), (0,25), (25,25), (25,0)). During each game tick, call `move(ghost_movement)`. During rendering, draw the ghost at `getCurrentPosition()`.

Answer (score 1):

A much better approach for simple AI along these lines is to use way points instead. Something along the lines of:

```
struct AIActor
{
    AIActor( const Vector3& a_Origin ) : m_CurrentTarget( 0 ), m_Speed( .5f )
    {
        m_WayPoints.push_back( a_Origin + Vector3( 0.f, 0.f, 25.f ) );
        m_WayPoints.push_back( m_WayPoints.back() + Vector3( 25.f, 0.f, 0.f ) );
        m_WayPoints.push_back( m_WayPoints.back() + Vector3( 0.f, 0.f, -25.f ) );
        m_WayPoints.push_back( m_WayPoints.back() + Vector3( -25.f, 0.f, 0.f ) );
    }
    void Update( const float a_Delta )
    {
        const Vector3& targetWP( m_WayPoints[ m_CurrentTarget ] ), &currentPos( GetPosition() );
        Vector3 diff( targetWP - currentPos );
        float diffLen = diff.Length();
        diff *= std::min( m_Speed * a_Delta, diffLen ) / diffLen; // Moves us along at m_Speed, but if length is less than speed, then we stop at the waypoint
        Vector3 newPos( currentPos + diff );
        if( newPos.FuzzyEquals( targetWP ) ) // At the waypoint, move to next one!
            m_CurrentTarget = m_CurrentTarget + 1 % m_WayPoints.size();
        SetPosition( newPos );
    }
    unsigned int m_CurrentTarget;
    std::vector< Vector3 > m_WayPoints;
    float m_Speed;
};
```

Not tested, but that's the gist of it. This is much more manageable and usable for moving around more than just a square.